# generate href for a link based on id using javascript

Tags: javascript, href, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use JavaScript to create an ID for my links and also to tell it where to link to.

My JavaScript has generated a link element in my HTML:

```
<a id = "NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG"> Link Text </a>
```

And that appears as it should.

I then have a variable eopartnum[i]:

```
console.log(eopartnum[i]); //output: NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG
```

This variable matches my ID for my link above. Then i tried to access that link via the ID and assign an href to it, like so:

```
var linktoprod = document.getElementById(eopartnum[i]);
console.log(linktoprod); //returns null
linktoprod.href = "http://www.enviroptics.com/"; //Cannot set property 'href' of null(…)
```

Why does my linktoprod come up as null? Is my syntax wrong?

JSfiddle for full code: http://jsfiddle.net/98oL12tk/17/   Lines 106-109 in JS section.

Comment: The link isn't on the DOM yet- so the get returns null

Comment: put i=0........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `getElementById()` before you append the table to the document. At the time that you are querying for the ID, it doesn't yet exist. This example seems a bit contrived; I think you could just set `firstcelllink.href = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/';`

*EDIT:* probably more appropriate to use `firstcelllink.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.enviroptics.com/');`

Comment: oh, didnt realize you could just set hrefs like that... that makes my life a lot easier haha, thanks

Comment: No problem. I made a small update, probably more appropriate to use `setAttribute` versus setting href directly, but either should work in this case.